# Python on Windows: Cannot run freezed app using pynput - platform is not supported

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze, pynput, python-3.10

On 64bit version of Windows 11 using cx_Freeze 6.10, I am trying to freeze into an EXE file a Python application which when run using the `python AccessibleWindowSwitcher.py` command runs without a problem. However, when I try to run the AccessibleWindowSwitcher.exe file generated by cx_Freeze, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\asamec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 113, in run
    module_init.run(name + "__main__")
  File "C:\Users\asamec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\Lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 15, in run
    exec(code, module_main.__dict__)
  File "AccessibleWindowSwitcher.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\asamec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from . import keyboard
  File "C:\Users\asamec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
    backend = backend(__name__)
  File "C:\Users\asamec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend
    raise ImportError('this platform is not supported: {}'.format(
ImportError
```

The python version I am using for both running via `python AccessibleWindowSwitcher.py` and freezing is Python 3.10.5 32 bit.

The problem is obviously in the pynput library, but I have no clue what can be causing the error only when running the EXE file.

Answer (score 1):

So I found a temporary fix for this issue. The problem was indeed in the pynput library, which for some reason failed to import some platform dependent modules. The fix requires to modify the installed pynput library, so updating the pynput library in the future, using `pip install --upgrade pynput` for instance, wil bring this problem back again.

### Fix on Windows

#### Changes in the `keyboard` package of pynput

1. Go to "\Lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard".
2. Open the "**init**.py" file.
3. At the begining of the file, add the following import: `from pynput.keyboard import _win32`
4. Find the line: `backend = backend(__name__)` and replace it with the line: `backend = _win32`

#### Changes in the `mouse` package of pynput

1. Go to "\Lib\site-packages\pynput\mouse".
2. Open the "**init**.py" file.
3. At the begining of the file, add the following import: `from pynput.mouse import _win32`
4. Find the line: `backend = backend(__name__)` and replace it with the line: `backend = _win32`

### Fix on macOS and Linux

On macOS or Linux, follow the same steps as above, but replace the occurances of "win32" with the following depending on your platform:

- On macOS, replace "win32" with "darwin".
- On Linux,replace "win32" with "xorg".

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to compile without modifying the module code. It's possible to do something similar to [this reply](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/312#issuecomment-710110753), which suggests a solution for pyinstaller, in cx_Freeze `setup.py`:

```py
build_exe_options = {
    "includes": ["pynput.keyboard._win32", "pynput.mouse._win32"]
}

executables = [
    Executable("main.py", base=None)
]

setup(
    name="YourAppName",
    version="0.1",
    description="Your application description",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables=executables
)
```